# Is parameter in self executing function necessary?

Tags: javascript, callback

I would like to know if this JavaScript code example below contains a useless parameter. I am learning about JavaScript webworkers and multithreadness, and the tutorial I am going through has the following piece of code:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (
    function (callback) {
        return 
            window.requestAnimationFrame 
            || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
            || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame 
            || window.oRequestAnimationFrame 
            || window.msRequestAnimationFrame 
            || function (callback) {
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 30);
            };
    }
)();
```

I have not used self-executing functions in JS much, but I can't figure out the purpose of the `callback` parameter in wrapping function. My understanding is that putting parameters into the opening function is only valid if the closing `()` also contains the variables to pass in.

The interior function `callback` parameter makes sense as it is attempting to replicate a "30 frames per second" action.

My presumption is that the `callback` parameter in the outside anonymous function is useless in this context, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Not only is that parameter unnecessary, as the answers correctly state, but that entire self-invoked function is unnecessary. You could just as easily write `window.requestAnimFrame = func1 || func2 || ... || func3;`.

Comment: @Ixrec Okay, that makes sense too. The tutorial I am going through was not dealing at all with self-executing functions. I am still a bit lost as to why they decided to just throw one in here, and use in what appears to be a poor example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is useless.

At each `function (...) {` block-opener, you're starting a new variable scope - anything inside of there, or in the function's arguments, has a separate scope. Any variables from functions one level up in the tree are still accessible, unless in this case you've reused their name.

The first `callback` parameter is essentially never referenced in the code.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. I guess there's nothing mysterious or special about self-executing functions. Even though the name `callback` is being used in the interior function, it is, in effect creating a new variable scoped to the interior anonymous function. The fact that `callback` was also used in the outer function has no bearing on the `callback` that's used in the `setTimeout`. Thanks!